Adding multiple files to TAR archive's root directory without creating an enclosing directory
Suppose I have the following files that I'd like to write to a .tgz file:
myfiles
|___file1.txt
|___file2.txt

Note that I'd like to write just the files (and not their enclosing directory) to the archive file. In other words, when I extract the .tgz file, I want to see file1.txt and file2.txt (not the parent directory myfiles) at the root of the archive.
When I try to accomplish this using python's built-in tarfile package, I do the following in order:

Use tarfile.open("myArchive.tgz", "w:gz") to initialize the archive and create the TarFile object
Use TarFile.add("myfiles/file1.txt", "file1.txt") to add one file to the TarFile object
Use TarFile.close() to close the archive file.

If I run the steps above as written, everything works fine and I'm able to create an archive with one single file at its root, with no parent folder. However, if I run the steps above but repeat step 2 more than once (say, using a for loop to add multiple files to the archive), tarfile instead creates an archive file with a directory called myArchive at its root, which then contains file1.txt and file2.txt. In other words, when extracted the archive file looks like this:
myArchive
|___file1.txt
|___file2.txt

Why does it do this? How can I accomplish having both file1.txt and file2.txt at the root of my archive file?
Steps to reproduce:
Environment info:
Python version: 3.10.13, OS: MacOS 14.1.1 (23B81), CPU Architecture: M2 Pro (arm64)

Create the directory myFiles as shown above somewhere on your computer
Run the following code, and observe the directory structure of the created archive file

tar = tarfile.open("myArchive.tgz", 'w:gz')
tar.add("myFiles/file1.txt", "file1.txt")
tar.add("myFiles/file2.txt", "file2.txt")
tar.close()


Comment out one of the tar.add() line and run again. Observe the directory structure of the created archive file.

What I'd hope would happen is that file1.txt and file2.txt would be at the root of the archive file, instead of having the folder myArchive at the root of the archive.

I could not reproduce the problem on a Linux machine. It worked for me as expected.

More details needed to reproduce your problem. The code  works as expected on Ubuntu with Python 3.11.

I added some information about my environment so hopefully folks are able to reproduce. What other env info should I add?

I figured out the issue. When uncompressing the archive, I'd double-click the .tgz file that I made. Turns out doing this uses MacOS's Archive Utility program to uncompress, which is what in turn creates the enclosing folder that I found so problematic. To properly uncompress it, go through the terminal following these steps and everything works perfectly. Sorry for kicking up dust!

While it's great that you found a solution, answers that rely heavily on links are discouraged for these reasons. Please consider updating your answer so that it is self-contained, with the minimal amount of code and instructions required to demonstrate how it works. Thanks
